# X-Editable Bootstrap field loads only on the first link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [Bootstrap X-Editable](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/index.html) along with [bootstrap-wysihtml5](https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5).

I have a comment list on every post page with an edit link under each comment.

But I can only edit the first comment on the last (the newest submitted comment) and the rest simply don't load the X-Editable field.

```
            $('#note').editable({
                validate: function(value) {
                    if($.trim(value) == '')
                        return 'Value is required.';
                },
                type: 'wysihtml5',
                title: 'Edit Comment',
                placement: 'top',
                send:'always',
                ajaxOptions: {
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'post'
                }
            });
            $('#pencil').click(function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#note').editable('toggle');
            });
```

And the HTML

```
<div id="note" 
     class="note" 
     data-type="wysihtml5" 
     data-toggle="manual" 
     data-pk="{{ $each_comment->id }}" 
     data-placement="top" 
     data-url="{{ url($each_comment->post_id . '/comment/update') }}">
    {!! $each_comment->comment !!}
</div>

<a href="#" 
   id="pencil" 
   class="pencil" 
   data-type="wysihtml5" 
   data-toggle="manual" 
   data-pk="{{ $each_comment->id }}" 
   data-placement="top" 
   data-url="{{ url($each_comment->post_id . '/comment/update') }}">
<i class="icon-pencil" style="padding-right: 5px"></i>[edit]
</a>
```

**UPDATE**

I made some changes, I added a `pen` class to the edit link

`<a href="#" id="pencil" class="pen" data-pk="{{ $each_comment->id }}">[edit]</a>`

And I call it with `a.pen`

```
('a.pen').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($('#note').attr("data-pk"));
    $('#note').editable('toggle');
});
```

Now all edit links are loading the X-Editable field but they're all showing the same comment with id `142` which is the latest submitted comment.

`console.log` prints the same id whenever I click on the edit link.

Answer (score 0):

From `$('#note').editable(` it looks like you're dynamically generating content with duplicate `id`.

`id` selector always returns the first match because the rule is, `id` should be unique in a document .

You should be using `class`, `name` or similar attributes that is allowed to be repeated instead of `id`.

So using `class` the code should be something like following:

```
$('.pencil').click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).prev('.note').editable('toggle');
 });
```

Comment: If I use `$('.note').editable()` it will start loading comments that aren't mine, the rest of the edit links open but they all load that one comment that isn't mine.

Comment: Your new snippet gave me this error in the console `Uncaught TypeError: this.prev is not a function`

Comment: this disabled all the edit links, none of them opened, not even the first comment.

Comment: I have `data-pk` that is unique and dynamic, can I use that instead of the id?

Comment: yes you can use `data-*` attributes. I might be able to help you with this if you can create a stack snippet/ jsfiddle or something with your code

Comment: @Halnex Assuming you're loading comments without a full page refresh, when you add new comments are you initializing the new comments are `editable()` ? I'm not sure whether it'll work otherwise (I don't think it'll). But I'm sure the `$('.pencil').click` event handler won't work unless you attach the to the new comment or use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: yes I am reinitializing it on comment submit but it's still not working. I'm not sure if I can create a jsfiddle, there's a lot of php in there. However, I already have the project on github, would that help? Or how can I do the jsfiddle without the php?

Comment: I've created this jsfiddle, not sure if it'll help https://jsfiddle.net/t18kjzLw/1/

Comment: I made some changes, now all edit links are loading the x-editable field, but they're all loading the same comment (the newest one) and `console.log($('#note').attr("data-pk"));` prints the same id over and over.

Comment: @Halnex unfortunately the fiddle doesn't replicate what you're mentioning. `console.log($('#note').attr("data-pk"));` will always print the same value because `$('#note')` id an `id` selection like i mentioned in answer

Comment: Changing it to use a class instead doesn't help, it doesn't load any editable field.